# Url link color in textView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

How to change link color in text View. In text view using  dataDectorType property and it show link in blue color. Is it possible to change in other color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to take a look at [Three 20 UI](http://three20.info/overview#UI). They have an example for Label with different style. For the UITextView, I see no way to do that